# How to make partition space usable

Tags: partitioning, gparted, vmware

I have Ubuntu 23.04 on VMware working great. But lately it filled all my disk space. On investigation I found out it is not using my entire allocated space of 128GB. 50% of the space is under unused section. `df -h` also shows only 50% utilization.

I tried various options `gparted`, `parted`, `fdisk`, etc. but none could extend or make use of that unused space. This is how details look like this

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: PLease include output of `sudo vgdisplay`

Answer (score 2):

Before you do anything, you should have a backup. Maybe you can take a snapshot of your VM in VMware.

The Ubuntu installer has probably used only about 50% of your LVM space unassigned. You have a physical volume of 127 GB, and an LVM space of 63 GB.

If you run `sudo vgdisplay` you should see that you have free space of about 63 GB.

To resize to use all of the remaining space:

```
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

This has expanded the volume, however you will have to resize the filesystem that sits on top of it as well.

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

Finally, you should be able to type `df -h` to see your reclaimed space.