# something wrong disk size in vm under KVM

Tags: virtualization, disk, storage, virt-manager

My VM in KVM looks disk full, then I checked df

```
df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              392M  1.2M  391M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /**
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/vda2                          1.8G  251M  1.4G  16% /boot
tmpfs                              392M  4.0K  392M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Then check from the host machine for the size of the VM

```
df -h /mnt/ktrader-srv/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1       229G   21G  197G  10% /mnt/ktrader-srv
```

In the virt-manager display VM size is 110G.
[image: virt-manager]

I am unsure how to sync among all the different sizes (host/vm inside/virt-manager).
Could anyone help how to fix this issue?

Comment: Your partition size in the VM is 10G for the partition of concern as shown in your `df` output. The overall size of the VM isn't the problem - that is a different thing. Consider expanding the partition in the VM. Likely you have a lot of unallocated space on the virtual disk. Running `lsblk -e7  -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,PARTLABEL,SIZE,FSUSED,MOUNTPOINT` in the VM might shed some light

Comment: You could include output of `sudo vgdisplay` as well. This might be of some help too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1486576/how-to-make-partition-space-usable

Answer (score 0):

After all search, I got to know this is related to LVM.

```
sudo lvm lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

And then,

```
sudo resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

After log out and login again, it display as actual VM file size.

```
df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              392M  1.7M  390M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   18G  9.4G  7.7G  55% /
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/vda2                          1.8G  251M  1.4G  16% /boot
tmpfs                              392M  4.0K  392M   1% /run/user/1000
```

If I wanted to use 100G as virtual disk size, then maybe need to extend using qemu-img upto this size.

I found this answer here, [https://itzone.com.vn/en/article/extend-lvm-disk-on-linux-ubuntu-22-04/#:~:text=sudo%20lvm%20lvextend%20-l%20%2B100%25FREE%20%2Fdev%2Fubuntu-vg%2Fubuntu-lv%20Continue%20command,check%20if%20the%20hard%20drive%20has%20been%20added](https://itzone.com.vn/en/article/extend-lvm-disk-on-linux-ubuntu-22-04/#:%7E:text=sudo%20lvm%20lvextend%20-l%20%2B100%25FREE%20%2Fdev%2Fubuntu-vg%2Fubuntu-lv%20Continue%20command,check%20if%20the%20hard%20drive%20has%20been%20added)